# Using Open Graph API, can I see when users Add To Playlist or Star tracks in Spotify?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spotify, facebook-opengraph

How would I access when a user (and a friend of a user) adds a song to a playlist, or stars a song in Spotify, Rdio etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens

http://graph.facebook.com/me/music.playlists

You have to get the `user_actions.music` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/) before you can read those.

Comment: Does this actually work yet? adding those permissions to "scope" returns an error, and adding to "perms" as the referenced example does doesn't seem to do anything (no new auth dialog and music.listens returns empty collection). Is there some other necessary piece?

Comment: This is not live to users yet, only developers until Timeline launches.

Comment: Thanks....but what does that mean exactly? I'm a developer, use the developer app (and so see timeline), but can't get this to work. Is it being specifically enabled/whitelisted for certain apps? I'm happy to wait it out and assume that it will start working at some point, but if there's something I could do now - or if I'm doing something wrong - I'd love to know.

Comment: I would also like to see additional documentation about this.

Comment: As asked in the original question- how do you get listens for friends and friends of friends (FQL?)?

Answer (score 11):

The correct permissions is user_actions:music, not a dot.

- user_actions:music
- user_actions:video
- user_actions:news

http://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens

http://graph.facebook.com/me/music.playlists

Those 2 endpoints still returns empty arrays.

Comment: The colon indicates 'global' and the '.' is a delimeter between app namespace and action type (i.e `music:listens` refers to global listens of music (i.e Spotify, Deezer, Rdio,etc) - `music.listens` refers to 'listens' actions registered to 'apps.facebook.com/music'

Comment: @Igy it is actually the inverse. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/

Comment: *facepalm* thanks; not sure how i got it not only wrong, but COMPLETELY wrong