# How can I access the read permissions for built in verticals?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/, I can prompt a user for the permission "user_actions.music" and have access to their actions on the open graph. I've enabled the Enhanced Auth Dialog setting on my test app but am receiving an invalid parameter error when I try to prompt a user for that permission.  I've also tried prompting the user for "user_actions" and experience the same error. Is this permission not active yet, even though I'm a developer or am I asking for this permission incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Open Graph isn't live to users yet. Only developers of your app should be able to grant these permissions.

Comment: Looking into it a little further, I found that there's an error in the docs for that permission, http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/18195131854745, the name of the permission should be user_actions:music rather than user_actions.music

Comment: Even after getting the auth dialog to prompt for the correct permissions by asking for user_actions:music, none of the activity permissions are being saved

Comment: Sounds like the same issue from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540124/using-open-graph-api-can-i-see-when-users-add-to-playlist-or-star-tracks-in-spot/7541189#7541189, btw I'm a developer trying to grant these permissions to my own test app