# How to get music listening data from Facebook/Spotify?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spotify, facebook-timeline

I'm trying to make an app that uses the list of songs that a user has been listening to on spotify. i.e on a user's profile page (with timeline enabled), you can see Recent Activity under Music, and see the songs he's been listening to. Is there an API feature from Spotify or Facebook that allows developers to access this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to get it from the new Facebook API as soon as it's out of beta.

See this question for more details: [Using Open Graph API, can I see when users Add To Playlist or Star tracks in Spotify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540124/using-open-graph-api-can-i-see-when-users-add-to-playlist-or-star-tracks-in-spo)

If you're using `libspotify`, you can get the user's Top Artists from there instead.