# Is there an Facebook API to retrieve music recent activity, especially music on Spotify?

Tags: facebook, spotify

I want to get songs list which played in Spotify, and I could see it under 'recently activity' feed, but how to get those recently activity feed info Using facebook API?

Yes, I know I could get common feed by 'me/feed', but is there a way to get recently activity feed like 'me/activity feed'?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Facebook has prepared the api for it, but it is not working yet. I guess it will be available on https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens at some point.

Read more here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/read/ and

[Using Open Graph API, can I see when users Add To Playlist or Star tracks in Spotify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540124/using-open-graph-api-can-i-see-when-users-add-to-playlist-or-star-tracks-in-spo)