# Spotify Apps API: get other users' playlists

Tags: spotify

Is there a way to get public playlists that are not your own? Or can I crank up the number of tracks that are returned from `social.getToplist()`?

Context: I'm writing a little App that lets you specify some users and then creates a playlist based on what those users listen to (Think party playlist). The only thing I've found to achieve that is to get their top tracks via `social.getToplist()` - but that returns only 20 tracks per user, which isn't that much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not available in the Spotify Apps API.

We recommend using Facebook's API to get social connections.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I've searched the FB API docs and couldn't find anything that would return the users' favourite tracks or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the graph Api from facebook for that kind of stuff.

There is also an [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540124/using-open-graph-api-can-i-see-when-users-add-to-playlist-or-star-tracks-in-spo) here for that way on stackoverflow.

An other way could be to let the user drag playlists and songs in your app, you submit the uris to your server and save that stuff together with an public username. If multiple users do that you can create those party playlists and much more i think.